# Error: "Autoloader expected class... typo error" but no typo in symfony 4 class inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, class, inheritance

I've got a class file "Ajuste.php":

```
<? // src/App/Entity/Ajuste.php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\SuperClass\Documento as Documento;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class Ajuste extends Documento
{
    /** 
     * @Id 
     * @Column(type="integer") 
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    private $name;

...more fields and methods
}
```

The superclass "Documento.php" lives in another folder:

```
<? // src/SuperClass/Documento.php

namespace App\SuperClass;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass 
 * */
class Documento
{
    /** @ORM\Column(type="DateTime") */
    protected $fecha_emision;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="DateTime") */
    protected $fecha_registro;

    ...more fields and methods
}
```

services.yaml is:

```
[...]
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your                         services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as     commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Admin,Resources,SuperClass}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
[...]
```

Problem starts when I try to `php bin/console make:migration` or `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`. 
Error is:

```
In DebugClassLoader.php line 204:

The autoloader expected class "App\SuperClass\Documento" to be defined in file "[more dirs]../src/SuperClass/Documento.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.`
```

The fact is that I can't make it to work, the error keeps appearing even if I remove "SuperClass" directory from the exclusion list in services (in which case the error is still there and also points out a typo in services.yaml), but I think that it should be something with the changes in symfony 4 and it seems I can't figure it out. Thank you in advance.

**Edit**:
Screenshot of the directory structure, just in case.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WdF5.jpg)

**Edit**:
Added Composer Autoload section:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

Comment: where is the use statement of Documento in src/App/Entity/Ajuste.php?

Comment: Sorry, added, it was there from the beginning. Still same error.

Comment: PS: For what it's worth, in general it's better to use English in your code (class, field names, etc). It's the universal tech language and everyone would understand your code more easily. Mixing English and Spanish makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Just for grins, make sure the files you are looking at are the same ones that the app is using.  May sound strange but it's not as rare as you might think to be working in one directory while the app is actually in another.

Comment: show your composer.json, autoloader section please.

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa added in last edit.

Comment: @Blizki could you try to change the section and make composer dumpautoload?
Change the psr-4 line ` "psr-4": { "App\\": ["src/App/”, “src/SuperClass/“] } `. Like here https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa Given that the SuperClass is in the App namespace, it is difficult to see how your suggestion could help.

Comment: @ViktarPryshchepa Symfony 4 "App" lives in src folder, that suggestion leads to an error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Kernel" from namespace "App".`
`Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel"? in [..dir..]/bin/console:36`

Comment: But you have class in folder App and your App namespace is mapped to src, not the app folder. You have full name *App\Entity\Ajuste* but not *App\App\Entity\Ajuste*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted both classes, then I made them again using `php bin/console make:entity` command and no errors.
It seems there was some kind of error in the ORM annotations.

From there, I ran `php bin/console make:migration` command and `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` but the generated migration file inside src/Migrations has another namespace than "App" so I had to add "Migrations" folder to exceptions in services.yaml so it reflects that change and omits the folder when looking for classes:

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{Entity,Admin,Resources,SuperClass,Migrations}'
```

And then, no errors ☺

I just wanted to point this out in case someone steps on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without a `use` statement, the PHP autoloader searches in the same directory for that `Documento` class to load it.

Adding `use App\SuperClass\Documento` in `src/App/Entity/Ajuste.php` should solve your problem

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, that line was there from the beginning but forgot to add it. Still, same error.

Comment: Have you checked the filenames properly? Are they really given in the same case?

Comment: Yep, triple checked those names, but here is a screenshot of the filename and directory structure(https://imgur.com/a/PNnn3mR)  just in case.